# Flowplayer Facebook Integration

Tags: facebook, flowplayer

I need help integrating flowplayer into facebook. I have done a lot of research and know that I am very close. I think that my only problem is the syntax that I use for the URL, which is here:

[http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf?config=%7B%27clip%27%3A%7B%27url%27%3A%27http%3A%2F%pearlsquirrel.com%2Fmp3%2FeggoAngel%20[Cover]_mixdown.mp3%27%7D%7D](http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf?config=%7B%27clip%27%3A%7B%27url%27%3A%27http%3A%2F%pearlsquirrel.com%2Fmp3%2FeggoAngel%20%5bCover%5d_mixdown.mp3%27%7D%7D)

I keep getting the error

> 300: Player initialization failed Error #1009.

I know that I almost have it working because I can see the Flash player in facebook, it just gives me this error.  Can someone please check my syntax of the above link and tell me if it is correct and if you know how to solve this problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a / sign what is %2F, but there is just a % sign. So the right url should be:

http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf?config=%7B%27clip%27%3A%7B%27url%27%3A%27http%3A%2F%2Fpearlsquirrel.com%2Fmp3%2FeggoAngel%20[Cover]_mixdown.mp3%27%7D%7D

I don't exactly know where do you use this url, here is the url without encode:

```
http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf?config={'clip':{'url':'http://pearlsquirrel.com/mp3/eggoAngel [Cover]_mixdown.mp3'}}
```

Please try it.

Comment: Thank you.  However, I still seem to get the same error.  It is very strange.

Comment: I use it to get data so that I can have an embedded flash player in facebook.

Comment: I have never tried, but I don't think so it is working. Here a solution: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4591764/how-to-embed-my-own-video-player-in-facebook